# How to do Group by in Discussion Board in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, view, discussion-board

Can any one please help on this, how to create a "group by" for discussion board in SharePoint 2013.

In list setting,i clicked on the view in the group by i selected a column,but the output is showing as below.

[image]

Comment: what column you have selected in the view to group by with?

Comment: i mean the column  name like subject or created by  or something else. and try grouping the column byt another coumn name and changing the view of the discussion board

Comment: i already tried couple of times,with multiple columns..:)

Comment: Can any one help on this?